# environment variables during docker image build to ACR deployed with Azure devops pipeline

Tags: c#, azure, docker, yaml

I'm trying to containerize my C# .NET6 project. it consists of different API's.
The project uses Azure keyvault in order to connect to an Azure SQL DB, and an Azure CosmosDB. The service principal credentials the application uses gets injected upon startup of the application.

I've configured my program.cs as this, and have configured env credentials locally:

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);


var credential = new ChainedTokenCredential(new DefaultAzureCredential(), new EnvironmentCredential());
var secretClient = new SecretClient(new Uri("https://kvurl"), credential);

builder.Configuration.AddAzureKeyVault(secretClient, new KeyVaultSecretManager());
```

This runs fine locally from my IDE and the application gets access to Azure keyvault during startup.

My Dockerfile looks like this:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0 AS build
WORKDIR /source



ARG AZURE_CLIENT_ID

ENV AZURE_CLIENT_ID $AZURE_CLIENT_ID

ARG AZURE_CLIENT_SECRET

ENV AZURE_CLIENT_SECRET $AZURE_CLIENT_SECRET

ARG AZURE_TENANT_ID

ENV AZURE_TENANT_ID $AZURE_TENANT_ID

# Copy everything
COPY . ./
# Restore as distinct layers
RUN dotnet restore 
# Build and publish a release
RUN dotnet publish -c release -o /app --no-restore

# Build runtime image
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:6.0
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=build /app ./




ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "Portal-backend.dll"]
```

if I use the CLI and build an image I'm not able to run the container unless I pass ClientID, ClientSecret and TenantID as env-arguments as following:

```
docker run -it --env AZURE_CLIENT_ID=ID \
    --env AZURE_CLIENT_SECRET=SECRET \
    --env AZURE_TENANT_ID=ID \
    -t name.azurecr.io/portal/portal-backend:latest
```

I have a CICD pipeline in Azure devops set up that I currently pass the secrets/id's through that I hoped was gonna inject the credentials to the application so that it actually can run the image once started.

The Yaml-file looks like this:

```
stages:
  - stage: Dev
    displayName: Dev
    jobs:
      - deployment:
        environment: portal-dev
      - job: Build
        steps:
        - task: Docker@2
          displayName: Build a docker image
          inputs:
              command: build
              repository: $(imageRepository)
              dockerfile: '**/Dockerfile'
              containerRegistry: $(dockerRegistryServiceConnection)
              tags: |
                $(buildIdTag)
                latest
              arguments: '
                --build-arg AZURE_CLIENT_ID=$(AZURE_CLIENT_ID)
                --build-arg AZURE_CLIENT_SECRET=$(AZURE_CLIENT_SECRET)
                --build-arg AZURE_TENANT_ID=$(AZURE_TENANT_ID)'
                

        - task: Docker@2
          displayName: Push docker image to Azure Container Registry
          inputs:
              command: push
              repository: $(imageRepository)
              containerRegistry: $(dockerRegistryServiceConnection)
              tags: |
                $(buildIdTag)
                latest
```

However, once I pull the image from Azure container registry, I'm still not able to just run the container without passing environment variables (client id, secret and tenant id) in the command.

if I pull the container and try to run it directly from docker desktop without passing any variables, I get this stacktrace and the credentials the application need in order to start, and connect to Azure keyvault is still not available:

```
Unhandled exception. Azure.Identity.CredentialUnavailableException: The ChainedTokenCredential failed to retrieve a token from the included credentials.

- DefaultAzureCredential failed to retrieve a token from the included credentials. See the troubleshooting guide for more information. https://aka.ms/azsdk/net/identity/defaultazurecredential/troubleshoot

- EnvironmentCredential authentication unavailable. Environment variables are not fully configured. See the troubleshooting guide for more information. https://aka.ms/azsdk/net/identity/environmentcredential/troubleshoot

- ManagedIdentityCredential authentication unavailable. Multiple attempts failed to obtain a token from the managed identity endpoint.

- Operating system Linux 5.10.16.3-microsoft-standard-WSL2 #1 SMP Fri Apr 2 22:23:49 UTC 2021 isn't supported.

- Stored credentials not found. Need to authenticate user in VSCode Azure Account. See the troubleshooting guide for more information. https://aka.ms/azsdk/net/identity/vscodecredential/troubleshoot

- Azure CLI not installed

- PowerShell is not installed.

- EnvironmentCredential authentication unavailable. Environment variables are not fully configured. See the troubleshooting guide for more information. https://aka.ms/azsdk/net/identity/environmentcredential/troubleshoot
```

which tells me the code cannot access Azure keyvault upon running the image.
Any help would be greatly appreciated, as I'm not sure what could be wrong, or if I've misunderstood anything. I simply want to be able to run the container without having to pass any secrets/ids as arguments in the docker run command.

Comment: i'd discourage you from trying to do what you are trying to do, instead these should be injected at runtime. else you store credentials in an image, which isn't a very good idea (security wise)

Comment: @4c74356b41 them I'm probably mistaken for how a docker container is used. I've only used Azure web apps and deployed my API's to an web app in order to expose my API's. If you're only supposed to inject the credentials upon running the image, that means I would have to give all users of the API's the credentials in order for them to run the container? I think I have some reading to do :)

Comment: i'd imagine they would need to use their own credentials or these containers need to be hosted on some platform

Comment: @4c74356b41 they are hosted in Azure container registry. If they are supposed to use their own credentials, they would need to create their own service principals in Azure and register it to my keyvault in order to gain access. The application needs access to Azure keyvault upon startup. This was easily achievable when I deployed to an Azure app service (with managed identy and service connection). However, this has not been straight forward when the app is containerized.

Comment: you can use containers with Azure App Service

Answer (score 1):

The error in your case is that environment variables are **not set properly**.

In your particular case the correct way would be:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0 AS build
WORKDIR /source

ARG AZURE_CLIENT_ID
ENV AZURE_CLIENT_ID=$AZURE_CLIENT_ID

ARG AZURE_CLIENT_SECRET   
ENV AZURE_CLIENT_SECRET=$AZURE_CLIENT_SECRET

ARG AZURE_TENANT_ID  
ENV AZURE_TENANT_ID=$AZURE_TENANT_ID

# Copy everything
COPY . ./
# Restore as distinct layers
RUN dotnet restore 
# Build and publish a release
RUN dotnet publish -c release -o /app --no-restore

# Build runtime image
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:6.0
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=build /app ./  

ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "Portal-backend.dll"]
```

However, generally this is a bad approach because this way you are storing secrets in your Docker image. Ideally you want to pass all secret values like connection strings, API keys etc. at runtime.

Comment: @cvita11 Thanks. However, I still get the same exception upon running the image. I think I need to do some research. My end goal is that a frontend application will consume my backend service. I need to look up how I can publish a container to an web app I guess (in Azure). Hopefully I can inject the credentials during runtime when publishing to the web app, that way I can achieve what I want.

Comment: In Azure WebApp service you have Configuration section with Application settings block where you can set your secrets.